# How to optimize Couchbase NQ1L ORDER BY

Tags: couchbase

Consider following use-case:

An Index

```
CREATE INDEX `type-index`ON bucket( type, createdAt) WHERE type='someType';
```

A query (which perform quite well)

```
SELECT a.*
FROM `bucket` a
WHERE a.tyoe='someType'
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10
```

**Execution: 14.51ms**

A query (which perform really bad)

```
SELECT a.*
FROM `bucket` a
WHERE a.tyoe='someType'
ORDER BY a.createdAt DESC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10
```

**Execution: 1m**

Here is an `EXPLAIN`

```
[
  {
    "plan": {
      "#operator": "Sequence",
      "~children": [
        {
          "#operator": "Sequence",
          "~children": [
            {
              "#operator": "IndexScan",
              "index": "type-index",
              "index_id": "ee6b75813c26795c",
              "keyspace": "bucket",
              "namespace": "default",
              "spans": [
                {
                  "Range": {
                    "High": [
                      "successor(\"someType\")"
                    ],
                    "Inclusion": 1,
                    "Low": [
                      "\"someType\""
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ],
              "using": "gsi"
            },
            {
              "#operator": "Parallel",
              "~child": {
                "#operator": "Sequence",
                "~children": [
                  {
                    "#operator": "Fetch",
                    "as": "a",
                    "keyspace": "bucket",
                    "namespace": "default"
                  },
                  {
                    "#operator": "Filter",
                    "condition": "((`a`.`_type`) = \"someType\")"
                  },
                  {
                    "#operator": "InitialProject",
                    "result_terms": [
                      {
                        "expr": "`a`",
                        "star": true
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "#operator": "Order",
          "limit": "10",
          "offset": "10",
          "sort_terms": [
            {
              "desc": true,
              "expr": "(`a`.`createdAt`)"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "#operator": "Offset",
          "expr": "10"
        },
        {
          "#operator": "Limit",
          "expr": "10"
        },
        {
          "#operator": "FinalProject"
        }
      ]
    },
    "text": "SELECT a.* FROM `bucket` a WHERE a.type='someType' ORDER BY a.createdAt DESC IMIT 10 OFFSET 10"
  }
]
```

The bucket contains 1.7M documents. Does exist any way how to improve the performance of ORDER BY? The value `createdAt` is a unix timestamp (number)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is create an index like this:

```
CREATE INDEX `type-index` ON bucket ( -createdAt ) WHERE type='sometType';
```

and the query

```
SELECT a.*
FROM `bucket` a
WHERE type='someType'
AND -createdAt IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY -createdAt
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10;
```

Comment: Basically the solution is to create the correct convering index and making sure you are using it.

Comment: better support for DESC is in plans and will be available in next release. For now, above solution should work/perform fine.